# how to select multiple database in session

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, session

how to set a different database for session in codeigniter

ex:

after user login.

user x database abc
user and database xyz

this is my database.php

```
$db['default'] = [
'dsn'          => '', // Not Supported
'hostname'     => APP_DB_HOSTNAME,
'username'     => APP_DB_USERNAME,
'password'     => APP_DB_PASSWORD,
'database'     => APP_DB_NAME,
'dbdriver'     => defined('APP_DB_DRIVER') ? APP_DB_DRIVER : 'mysqli',
'dbprefix'     => '', // Not Supported
'pconnect'     => false,
'db_debug'     => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on'     => false,
'cachedir'     => '',
'char_set'     => 'utf8',
'dbcollat'     => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre'     => '',
'encrypt'      => $db_encrypt,
'compress'     => false,
'stricton'     => false,
'failover'     => [],
'save_queries' => true,
];
```

and index.php
    $_SESSION['DB'] = 'gestor'; //default for select database of email

and my app-config.php

```
define('APP_DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('APP_DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('APP_DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('APP_DB_NAME', $_SESSION['DB']);
```

is always connecting in 'gestor', does not make the database exchange.

after validating the email of the user, I want to change the database by the registered, after the login I am doing so:

```
$_SESSION['DB'] = get_base_email ($email);
```

Comment: It all depends on how you build your statements.

If you put 'use database_name' before every statement, it should immediately use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

you cant redefine APP_DB_NAME without reload instance of codeigniter

```
&get_instance()
```

look for another way

Comment: try $this->session->sess_destroy()

Comment: What is your suggestion, I do not know how to solve this